# Can we disable cursor hand for admin grid?

Tags: magento

I have created a grid in admin panel. But when mouse pointer hovers over any row, cursor hand shows over it. But I don't have any link for particular row.

Can I disable cursor hand for admin grid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Grid.php define this method empty

```
public function getRowUrl($row) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks Deependra.. this solutions is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use custom renderers for solving this. You can add custom styles to rows and columns using the renderers. The method is described [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/). Give a try...

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `skin\adminhtml\default\default\boxes.css` and add css in the bottom

```
#custommodule_name_grid .grid tr.on-mouse, #custommodule_name_grid .grid tr.pointer{    
    cursor:default!important;
}
```

Magento automatically create div id as per your module name, if you see for sales order, then there will be "sales_order_grid".

So, check div id by firbug tool and updated div id value from css.

Hope will help![image]

Comment: Thanks Rajiv for suggestion. But I wanted to make it generalize as a plug & play custom module. So I think there could be a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

In grid class return false to getRowUrl()

> app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/XXX/Grid.php

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
  return false;
}
```